# TPL - is worth when working on same EXE for all files in a folder

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I have a antivirus scaning EXE which should run for all files under a folder. I am asked to do multithreading in scanning all the files as fast as it can.

So, thought of writing

```
public void InitiateTaskRunner()
{
   Log("Begening InitiateTaskRunner ::" + DateTime.Now);
   string[] Files = Directory.GetFiles(Utility.inputPath);
    Parallel.ForEach(Files, File=>
    {
        InitiateTaskWorker(File); //inside this I will call Scan EXE for specific file
        //fileID++;
    });
    Log("Ending InitiateTaskRunner ::" + DateTime.Now);
}
```

like this, in this case since Scan EXE is alone and though TPL creates multiple threads, all have to be executed the SCAN EXE in sequential order rather than concurrent? am I right?
Inside InitiateTaskWorker I will loop check the file with sCAN EXE to see if its safe or not, if its infected then will delete the file and update one report file and come back to Parallel.Foreach to pick up next file and it goes on..I hope supplied enough info now.

Comment: if it's for virus detection you should report something. and in your code you return nothing, which mean you either report nothing or you report as side effect. probably problematic.

Comment: Hi Patrick..inside the InitiateTaskWorker method I have SCAN.EXE location and will run the command to scan it.

Comment: inside InitiateTaskWorker method I have whether Scan is failed or not, if failed it will take appropriate action like delete the file and log the same. move to next ...

Comment: Edited original question to add more info on InitiateTaskWorker work

Comment: Does `InitiateTaskWorker()` make a call to .exe file?

Comment: Scanning files is mostly I/O bound, hence there is little gain in doing it concurrently since the access to disk memory is sequential